# What happens if I delete mails in my client (imap)

Tags: email, imap, claws-mail

I have a very small netbook with 16 GB SSD. Thus, I want to delete mails older than one month (using Linux claws-mail, but that's not crucial to the question).

The question is, since I'm using IMAP, if I'm deleting mails in my local client, will the emails remain on the server still?

Comment: No; if you delete emails from IMAP the the emails on the server will be removed of course you have only downloaded a cache of the server adjust the clients settings to manage the size of this cache

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using IMAP, if I'm deleting mails in my local client, will the emails remain on the server still?

Most likely not, IMAP is usually configured as a sync between the client and server.

Comment: So what should I do? Surely there must be a way to only keep recent mails locally?

Comment: yeah, configure it as POP3 and set it to keep copies on servers.